# A transition from svelte/transitions greatly slows down the website

Tags: javascript, html, performance, css-transitions, svelte

I have a project in svelte that I was developing and feels good.

but when I go to my android phone I see that when click it is delayed a lot.

---

from what I know svelte is the fastest framework because uses native javascript code as output (no virtual dom) but what is happening here is out of the world (inexplicable)

1000000x slower? what? how it even possible

---

so I started debugging and investigating.

and I found that without transition everything was fine, speed is good and everything.

but when starting using transition slow the website.

---

### debugging

with chrome devtools

[image]

when only adding `transition:scale`

like this `<div transition:scale>`

[image]

---

like you see more than 80% of speed is because that scale transition

[image]

---

### the solution

without `transition:scale`

[image]

| ❌before | ✅now |
| --- | --- |
| 3.12s | 5μs |

I'm not gonna lie but is like 1000000x faster than the with animation one.

## why? this happens

I know the solution, but I need some explanation or a way to have animation without very very slow things.

> the images you see on the top are the result of a very fast click on the button (like at least 20 times)

Comment: It may be based on the sheer amount of HTML that is being animated

Comment: Svelte is by no means the fastest framework, just take a look at the [benckmarks](https://krausest.github.io/js-framework-benchmark/current.html). Also, the Svelte `transition` directive is using JavaScript to animate the things so it cannot be more performant than similar functionality built in JQuery, as it runs in main thread and consume a lot of CPU with layout reflows. To have performant transitions you should use plain CSS to benefit from GPU acceleration.

Comment: I'm not sure why this transition is causing a perf hit (a repro would help), but the built-in Svelte transitions don't use JS to animate things - they construct a CSS animation using JS, and then apply it to the element as a regular CSS animation (which is off the main thread). See [the tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/custom-css-transitions)

Comment: @GeoffRich "*don't use JS to animate things - they construct a CSS animation using JS*" you are contradicting yourself with this statement, also the tutorial is useless in giving an answer related to technical implementation, you should have to look at the [source code](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/blob/master/src/runtime/transition/index.ts), just search for 'getComputedStyle' to see how many layout trashes Svelte does, and check out the [easing](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/blob/master/src/runtime/easing/index.ts) zero-CSS solution.

Comment: @n--: What Goeff is saying is: The JS is not used to set style properties in a loop, instead it generates the CSS for an animation and starts that. Hence, *not* a JS animation. The easing functions are used to calculate the property values in the CSS animation, never to set the properties directly.

Comment: `getComputedStyle` is commonly only used *once* to get an existing/start value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is called *layout thrashing*. It happens when you change or transitions CSS properties that cause style/layout recalculation. If these kinds of changes are applied to a list of many items, each one invalidates the calculations that came before it, wasting huge amounts of CPU time. (All the very small purple blocks at the bottom of the flame chart hint at this.)

To avoid this, you have to restrict your changes/transitions to those that do not cause these updates. The key here is that some properties like `transform` do not affect layout and happen in the compositor which is a GPU accelerated operation.

Also, even compositor transitions are not "free", so applying them to many individual items at the same time should be avoided.

---

I looked at the trace in detail because the Svelte transitions themselves are already compositor-only; the creation of the animation appears to cause style recalculation & layout:

[image]

This is probably because this code interacts with the `style.animation` property.

So either do not transition many items at once, or try class-based transitions.

Example for comparing the performance:

```html
<script>
    import { scale } from 'svelte/transition';
    
    let count = 1000;
    let svelte;
    let classBased;
</script>

<label>
    Item count
    <input type=number bind:value={count} />
</label>

<label>
    <input type=checkbox bind:checked={svelte}/>
    Svelte transition
</label>

<label>
    <input type=checkbox bind:checked={classBased}/>
    Class transition
</label>

{#each { length: count } as i}
    {#if svelte}
        <h1 transition:scale={{duration: 300}}>Hello</h1>
    {/if}
{/each}

{#each { length: count } as i}
    <h1 class="transition" class:show={classBased}>Hello</h1>
{/each}

<style>
    .transition {
        visibility: hidden;
        transform: scale(0);
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
    }
    .transition.show {
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1);
        transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s;
    }
</style>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/42973a5060e84bf9a336b209403464d7?version=3.50.1)

Comment: I'm using svelte for an analog clock and using `svelte/easing` (as opposed to `svelte/transition` used in this thread). I notice significant performance problems but I'm only animating one element (the second hand) and doing so every second. Any possible way to improve performance with vanilla CSS and/or JS?

Comment: If you are not using very particular easings, you probably can just use regular CSS animations/transitions. Animating one element really should not be a performance issue, though. I suggest you ask a separate question and show your code, then people can more easily suggest appropriate solutions.